# Helicoid with fixed parameters each time

Tags: differential-geometry, parametric, parametrization

Let

$A(r, \theta):=<r\cos \theta, r \sin\theta, \theta>$, $r \in[-1,1], \theta \in [0,2\pi]$ be the parameterization of an **area**. So this is obviously a helicoid.

(*) Let r be fixed and $\theta$ varying in the interval, then let $\theta$ be fixed and let r vary. what kind of curves would be obtain through this kind of variation? at which angle would they intersect?

---

So unfortunately I do not have any idea.

I tried to plot it here, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/usy8hfrtbx, for $\theta$ fixed I only got a straight line and for $r$ fixed I got kind of a helix?  Can this be right? how could I calculate the angle at which they intersect?

I would be thankful for inputs.

Comment: I can only presume that they're talking about the intersection of the lines when $r$ varies and $\theta$ is fixed at two different values?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Although that would make more sense, I read the task again and it first asked which kind of curves we obtain by letting one parameter fixed and the other varying and then it requested to calculate the angle which is ibtained by the two different kind of curves. But I don't know how to start here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! could you also tell me how  the intersection angles can be calculated here? they would be dependent of the choice of the fixed $\theta$, I assume?

Comment: Nope... they meet at $90^\circ$.  Think about it....

Comment: Ok, now I have calculated $\frac{\partial A}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta}$ and the product of those would always be zero. Would this suffice as reasoning that the angle would always be 90°?

Comment: Could you also tell me with which program you made the nice plot? Mathematica?

Comment: Yep.  *Mathematica*.

Comment: Show that the dot product vanishes.

Comment: Somehow my argumentation before was wrong, and calculating the dot product of the derivatives when one variable is fixed, did not lead me to =0. :( Could you tell me which dot product please? thank you

Comment: Look at the red and the blue lines.

Comment: I did and it is really clear that it should be 90°. But I do not know how to show it ? Thank you for getting back to me. $\partial A / \partial r \cdot \partial A / \partial \theta$ is 0, do you mean this dot product?

Comment: .........yep....